# Disable MenuStrip Dropdown in Windows Forms Application

Tags: winforms, menustrip

I am disabling the parent menu option in a Windows forms menustrip.  When you hover over it, the submenu still opens.  Is there a way to disable the submenu opening or do I have to disable all the submenu items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up looping through the DropDownItems and disabling them after I disable the main item.

```
for (int i = 0; i < this._menuOpen.DropDownItems.Count; i++)
{
    this.menuOpen.DropDownItems[i].Enabled = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Having the menu drop down show on mouse hover does not seem to be the default behavior of a `ToolStripMenuItem` and I could not find a property to enable this.

I did find [this post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vbgeneral/thread/d10bf643-aac8-464b-8b97-487237cfa0be) by someone who wanted this behavior, and you should check to see if there is a `MouseHover` event handler for the `ToolStripMenuItem` and check the `Enabled` property there:

```
private void toolStripMenuItem1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (toolStripMenuItem1.Enabled)
        toolStripMenuItem1.DropDown.Show(menuStrip1, new Point(0, 0));
}
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Just set the `Enable`property on the parent menu to `False`. In .net 2.0 and 3.5 the submenu will not show.

Also please try to be a little more specific.

Comment: This is not true.  It does show.  The first time you click on it, it does not, but if you click on it a second time it does.

Comment: I have just checked again, on a second computer and my result is valid. Maybe you should try and post more details, a screenshot maybe.