# How to disable menuitem and stop dropdown in ActionMainMenuBar?

Tags: delphi, menuitem

Delphi 10.4.2
I have a problem with my TActionMainMenuBar. When I disable a menuitem in code it appears disabled but if I dropdown an enabled menuitem next to it then move to the disabled menuitem its submenu drops down!
If this is not a bug is there a way to prevent the disabled menuitem from dropping down?

Thanks
Tony

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4055744/disable-menustrip-dropdown-in-windows-forms-application) help you ?

Comment: Not that I can see. That is VB and a different component.

Comment: What happens if you disable the menuitem, and loop over it's child items, setting these to invisible ? My thought was that a menuitem with zero visible child items would not drop down ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Will look further at this option if more problems crop up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to close menu in [`TActionMainMenuBar.OnPopup`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ActnMenus.TActionMainMenuBar.OnPopup) event when an item is disabled:

```
procedure TForm1.ActionMainMenuBar1Popup(Sender: TObject; Item: TCustomActionControl);
begin
  if not Item.Enabled then
    ActionMainMenuBar1.CloseMenu;
end;
```

However I don't recommend that, because it will also exit menu loop which may cause bad user experience.

The behavior you describe can be considered as defect and you could [report it to Embarcadero](https://quality.embarcadero.com/). To fix that in your code you should override method `CreatePopup` of `TActionMainMenuBar` to prevent creating popup menus (return `nil`) for disabled items. But returning `nil` in that method will cause another problem (access violation) when opening submenu using <kbd>↑</kbd> or <kbd>↓</kbd> on keyboard. Therefore you should handle that case too by patching `WMKeyDown`. Ideally you should derive your own class from `TActionMainMenuBar` or use an [interposer class](https://zarko-gajic.iz.hr/delphi-interceptor-classes-tbutton-classtbutton/):

```
type
  TActionMainMenuBar = class(Vcl.ActnMenus.TActionMainMenuBar)
  private
    procedure WMKeyDown(var Message: TWMKeyDown); message WM_KEYDOWN;
  protected
    function CreatePopup(AOwner: TCustomActionMenuBar;
      Item: TCustomActionControl): TCustomActionPopupMenu; override;
  end;

{ ... }


function TActionMainMenuBar.CreatePopup(AOwner: TCustomActionMenuBar;
  Item: TCustomActionControl): TCustomActionPopupMenu;
begin
  if Item.Enabled then
    Result := inherited CreatePopup(AOwner, Item)
  else
    Result := nil;
end;

procedure TActionMainMenuBar.WMKeyDown(var Message: TWMKeyDown);
begin
  if Assigned(Selected) and (not Selected.Control.Enabled) and
     (Orientation in [boLeftToRight, boRightToLeft]) and
     (Message.CharCode in [VK_UP, VK_DOWN]) then
    Exit; { do not try to popup disabled items }
  inherited;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks Peter. I meanwhile tried setting the menu item action to visible=false but it still appeared!! 
I added an onEnter event but I could not get it to execute - any ideas?
It also seems an action attached to a menuitem with subitems does not execute.

Comment: @Tony Setting action visibility works for me, at least in 10.3.3. Are you sure you are setting the visibility of action related to top level menu item? Top level items aren't usually connected to an action, because they are typically created by dragging and dropping the whole category from the `TActionManager` designer. And why would you want to use `OnEnter` event? Anyway, those are new questions not related to the original issue. Let's focus on the answer I provided. Did you try out the proposed fix?

Comment: Thanks I created an interposer class with your suggestion and it fixed the dropdown issue.
(If the onenter event fired it would be useful to configure the subitems in the menu)

Comment: You can manipulate with items in [`OnPopup`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ActnMenus.TActionMainMenuBar.OnPopup) event which occurs just before displaying a submenu. There is also [`OnEnterMenuLoop`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.ActnMenus.TCustomActionMenuBar.OnEnterMenuLoop) event which occurs each time an item is activated for the first time in menu loop. As always [remember to accept/upvote the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), if it was useful and helped you to resolve your issue